# Mac authentication to Apache-Kerberos

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, kerberos

I have an Apache server using Kerberos authentication to serve internal apps, using Active Directory as the KDC.  This works fine for Windows clients.  We have a few Mac clients and none of them can access the apps on Apache.  The Macs are on the domain and can access other network resources.

On my R&D Mac, I do a klist in bash and it shows my tickets.  The working tickets show up like CIFS/host.domain.com@domain.com.  On the other hand, I have HTTP/host@domain.com for the not working ticket.  I checked my Windows PC, and it has HTTP/host.domain.com@domain.com.

I know nothing about Mac, so I don’t really know even where to start.  Any suggestions?

Single AD domain running Win2012
OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Thanks

Comment: Do the `HTTP/host` and `HTTP/host.domain.com` SPNs belong to the same AD account? Do they both exist in Apache's keytab?

Comment: For some reason, Apache has both (it shouldn't).  I assume AD only has the fully-qualified version.  So Mac must be doing something different than Windows to pull back the short version from Apache.